# How to reduce times between Flink intra-jobs and avoid repeated tasks

Tags: apache-flink, flink-batch

I have run a Flink bounded job in standalone cluster. Then Flink breaks it down into 3 jobs.
It takes around 10 secs to start the next job after one job finish. How to reduce the times between jobs? and when observing the details of the tasks flow, I notice that 2nd job did the same tasks that have been done by 1st job, plus new additional tasks, and so on with 3rb job. For example, it repeatedly reads the data from files in every job and then join it. Why does it happen? I am a new Flink user. AFAIK, we can't cache dataset in Flink. Really need help to understand how it works. Thank you.

[image]

[Here is the code](https://github.com/isthabenahadirani/trance-flink/blob/master/executorFlink/src/main/scala/flinkutils/generated/Test2NNLSpark.scala)

Comment: Can you share the code for this job? I'm not sure what's going on, but maybe seeing the code will make it clear.

Comment: I have added the code in the question. Thanks! @DavidAnderson

Comment: I'm sorry, but that code is unreadable. I'm not sure why your job is being run 3 times -- but perhaps it is failing and being restarted. Have you examined the log files? I would look there for clues.